# IF Statement with OR Criteria and ISERROR

Tags: excel, error-handling, excel-formula

I have a formula that is not working.

```
=IF(OR(AC358="",ISERROR(AC358), AC358=0),VLOOKUP(M358,FCal,3,TRUE),VLOOKUP(AC358,FCal,3,TRUE)
```

Column AC has a vlookup in it that will either return a real value, 0, or an error #N/A.

When AC (the vlookup) returns a #N/A error the IF statement fails in its current format.

However, the IF Statement works when I either

1. hard code a real value or a zero into AC, or
2. if I replace the OR Criteria with just a single criteria `ISERROR(AC358)`

So I know the `ISERROR` is working by itself but it is not working inside the OR statement.

Comment: Are the values in the FCat named range sorted in an ascending manner?

Comment: Yes, and the nested vlookup to FCal is working fine. It is the ISERROR inside the OR statement that seems to be the problem

Comment: As an update, I have put a workaround in place by nesting the vlookup in AC into an If(ISERROR(vlookup...),0,vlookup(...)). That way AC will either be returning a successful value or else 0 and then my following IF OR works against it. Doesn't answer the why, but at least gets me a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking for an error with ISERROR or ISNA must be done separately from other calculations; you cannot nest an error check with more conventional criteria in an OR. An OR that includes a check on a cell that includes a #N/A will return #N/A, not TRUE or FALSE. `=IF(ACD358=0, TRUE, FALSE)` when ACD358 contains a #N/A error does not return FALSE; it returns #N/A.

```
=IF(ISNA(AC358), VLOOKUP(M358, FCal, 3), IF(OR(AC358="", AC358=0), VLOOKUP(M358, FCal, 3), VLOOKUP(AC358, FCal, 3)))
```

When the error check returns TRUE, processing passes immediately to the first M358 [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65); the other IF and OR are not calculated.

Given that a blank, zero or #N/A are likely to return another #N/A from FCal, perhaps this shorter version with [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) would be better.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(AC358, FCal, 3), VLOOKUP(M358, FCal, 3))
```

TRUE is the default for VLOOKUP's *range_lookup* parameter. Beyond including it for clarity, it is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped! An elegant alternative to what I have done.